# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass when doing a Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

When I add: `<p>Project: <%= @work.project.name %></p>` I get undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass 
I have everything up on Git except the below code that is causing the issue:

```
<h1><%= @work.datetimeperformed %></h1>

<p>User: <%= @work.user.fname %> <%= @work.user.lname %></p>

<p>Project: <%= @work.project.name %></p>

<p>Hours: <% @work.hours %></p>
```

On Git: https://github.com/gitchrisadams/timetracker

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like that:-

```
<p>Project: <%= @work.project.present? ? @work.project.name : "" %></p>
```

Here `@work` doesnot have any `project`, so the `project` of that `@work` is nil. So due to `@work.project.name`, it is throwing that error.

The relation should be like that:-

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works
end

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :name
  belongs_to :project
end
```

See this guide for [has many relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

Comment: Thanks Shamsul, So if I added a project to work in the database, I shouldn't get this error. I may have missed a step in the tutorial where I was supposed to add a project. I'll try that first and if that doesn't work, I'll try your code above.

Comment: How to I add a project to the @work so it is not nil. I attempted doing this in rails console but I'm not quite getting it. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: I added the attr_accessible :project_id, :name but I get this error: NoMethodError in WorksController#index
undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x4c20ed0>

Extracted source (around line #0):
                

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/work.rb:3:in `<class:Work>'
app/models/work.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/works_controller.rb:4:in `index'

Comment: @Hemali Works mode: class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Work belongs to a :project and to a :user
 attr_accessible :project_id, :name
 belongs_to :project
 belongs_to :user

Comment: @Hemali 
User:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #A User belongs to a company
 belongs_to :company

 # User has many works
 has_many :works
 
 # A User has many procets through the works they do. 
 # Get me all the projects this user worked on
 has_many :projects, :through => :works

Comment: @Hemali 
Projects:
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 # A project belongs to a company
 belongs_to :company

 # A Project has many works
 has_many :works
 
 # A Project has many users through the works, Get all users who performed work
 has_many :users, :through => :works
scope :lowdefaultrate, -> { where("default_rate < 100") }

Comment: @Hemali Company:
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 # A Company has many users and projects
 has_many :users
 has_many :projects

Comment: @ShamsulHaque Thanks for the help. Playing around with the database in Rails C I was able to manually assigned a project ID to my works items that corresponded with actual projects I had in the database, not nil items and now it works. Your post lead me in the right direction so thanks.